# get ajax response in jquery modal form dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't get the ajax response when submitting a modal dialog form. It works perfectly when the form is not modal.

The form:

```
<div id="form2" style="display: none">
    <form id="objectInsert" action="element/create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea> 
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here i get the ajax success part in the console!

```
$("#objectInsert").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    resetErrors();
    var form = this;
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        cahe:false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);//Working
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('there was a problem checking the fields');
        }
    });
});
```

Here i get the ajax error part in the console! can someone tell me where i'm doing wrong?

```
    $("#add_element").click(function(){
        $("#form2").dialog({
            modal:true,
            width:400,
            buttons:{
                Send:function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var form = $("#objectInsert");
                    var url = form.attr('action');
                    var data = new FormData(form[0]);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: url,
                        data: data,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cahe:false,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function(resp) {
                            console.log(resp);//not working
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            console.log('there was a problem checking  the fields');
                            console.log(xhr);
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;

                },
                Cancel:function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The controller

```
public function create() {
    try{
        $this->form = new Form();
        $this->form->post('name');
        $this->form->val('isEmpty', 'name');
        $this->form->post('description');
        $this->form->val('isEmpty', 'description');

        $this->form->fetch();
        $this->form->submit();

        $data = $this->form->get_postData();

        $this->model->insert($data);

        echo json_encode('success');
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $errors = $this->form->get_error();
        $_SESSION["errors"] = $errors;
        //This is for ajax requests:
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&  
                strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
                == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            echo json_encode($_SESSION['errors']);
            exit;
        }

        foreach ($_SESSION["errors"] as $errors){
            echo $errors;
            echo '<br/>';
        }exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the cause of the error in the console?

Comment: Use the parameters which are passed to the error handler: [`Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for that advice. i've added the error handler. the error thrown is : "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data return window.JSON.parse( data + "" );" This is console.log(error); line

Comment: The returned data is no valid JSON. Check the request and response in the network tab of the developer tools

Comment: @Andreas The request is the posted data ("name", "description"), but strangely the response is the HTML source code of the current page. i've updated my question with the controller function that returns the json data. please let me know if there's something wrong!

Answer (score -1):

see this code you have not closed the function block

```
success: function(resp) {
         console.log(resp);//not working
       },//This is not closed for success function
error: function() {
         console.log('there was a problem checking the fields');
       }
```

Comment: Ohh Sorry!,  My eye caught that first. :)

Comment: needs a comma also

Comment: Oh i'm sorry..i made those mistakes when editing my question here. I've added the missing codes. but that was not the cause of the problem